# Probability that a low weight polynomial has a irreducible factor of bounded degree

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,
I'm considering the following algorithm:
Let $K \in GF(2)[X]$  be a random low weight polynomial of weight $w$ and of degree $d$. 
The weight of a polynomial in $GF(2)$ is the number of non-zero coefficients. 
My goal is to compute the probability that $K$ has an irreducible factor of degree in $[d_{min}, d_{max}]$, with $d_{min}< d_{max} < d$.

Comment: You should precise the meaning of `smooth`and `weight`. Observe that there is at least two meanings for the latter. For Canaday (1st student of Carlitz) the weight of a polynomial $P \in GF(2)[t]$ is thenumber of solutions $A \in GF(2)[t]$ of the equation
$$
P = \sigma(A)
$$
while probably you do not want this notion...

Comment: You are right. The weight I'm interested in is the number of non zero coefficients.

Comment: Your question has a number of problems. What algorithm? What do you mean precisely by smooth? What do you mean by random smooth polynomial of degree $d$ and weight $w$? The smoothness condition might imply there aren't any, depending on what you mean by smooth.

Comment: Not that it's suggested by the text, or is standard terminology, but my guess is that "smooth" means squarefree.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify this issue:
By smooth, I mean low weight, i.e. $w\ll d$. 
The algorithm is the following one:
1) Draw a random polynomial $K$ of degree $d$ and weight $w$
2) Factor it into irreducible polynomials
3) Check whether one of these factors has a degree in $[d_{min}, d_{max}]$. 